# .NET7 SignalR freeze pages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr

So I have a .net 7 webapp using SignalR running in lan.

There is page A and a button calling an ajax get method and with its response result needs to invoke signalR to push data to a page B.

Then the page B has another button calling an ajax get method and with its response result need to invoke signalR to push data to a page C.

The .js file with the hub connection is in the share folder. At Control level, I inject the hub in the constructor and use it to send data to the listener pages from Action methods.

I cannot use Identity so my calls are like: Clients.Other..

On my PC with VS2022 all work fine, but on my IIS on WIN10 something is wrong: lost connection, page freezed and so on.

But I don't know SignalR so much to understand where could be the problem: ajax, session, win10, etc..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my PC with VS2022 all work fine, but on my IIS on WIN10 something is wrong: lost connection, page freezed and so on.

From your description, I believe there is no error in you code. As you know, there is connection limitation on the client operating system. [You can check this official doc, I know it's for asp.net signalr, but suggestion still useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting#connection-limit-reached).

**My suggestion**

If your webapp still in testing stage, you can use kestrel to run it, it could avoid the limitation.

If you want it running it in production environment, you should deploy it on windows sever system.

Comment: You're right, installing on Windows Server works fine. Tnx a lot.